# SQL: How to group elements in two arrays at corresponding positions together

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I need to combine `array1` and `array2` together, but their elements at corresponding positions should be grouped together. The length of `array1` and `array2` is high and combining them manually with

```
ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(
      ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(array1[1], array2[1]),
      ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(array1[2], array2[2]),
      ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(array1[3], array2[3])
      ...
    )
```

is a bad solution. Any advice on how it can be achieved?

Sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE sample_table AS (
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2022-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_column,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(1, 2, 3) AS array1,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(10, 20, 30) AS array2
  UNION
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2022-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_column,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(4, 5) AS array1,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(30, 40) AS array2
  UNION
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2022-01-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_column,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(6, 7, 8, 9) AS array1,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(60, 70, 80, 90) AS array2
);
```

[image]

Desired result:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMPORARY TABLE sample_table_2 AS (
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2022-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_column,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(1, 2, 3) AS array1,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(10, 20, 30) AS array2,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT([1,10],[2,20],[3,30]) AS array3
  UNION
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2022-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_column,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(4, 5) AS array1,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(30, 40) AS array2,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT([4,30],[5,40]) AS array3
  UNION
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2022-01-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_column,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(6, 7, 8, 9) AS array1,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(60, 70, 80, 90) AS array2,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT([6,60],[7,70],[8,80],[9,90]) AS array3
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two arrays are the same length, then you can use FLATTEN to build up the sub-arrays:

```
with data as (
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2022-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_column,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(1, 2, 3) AS array1,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(10, 20, 30) AS array2
  UNION
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2022-01-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_column,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(4, 5) AS array1,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(30, 40) AS array2
  UNION
  SELECT
    TO_DATE('2022-01-03', 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_column,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(6, 7, 8, 9) AS array1,
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(60, 70, 80, 90) AS array2
)
select d.*
    ,f.seq
    ,array_construct(d.array1[f.index], d.array2[f.index]) as sub_array
from data as d,
    table(flatten(input=>d.array1)) as f
```

[image]

and then [aggregate](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_agg?utm_source=legacy&utm_medium=serp&utm_term=array_agg) those back together like:

```
select d.*
    ,array_agg(array_construct(d.array1[f.index], d.array2[f.index])) within group (order by f.index) as array3
from data as d,
    table(flatten(input=>d.array1)) as f
group by f.seq,1,2,3;
```

giving the desired results:

[image]